# Regarding Filtering/looping and performing math in the same iteration of NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, sorting

i am trying to filter/loop and perform math within the same iteration but cant seem to find the right answer.
I have a numpy array, that is size 6, 2, and consists of two values that i want to minus together, however i want the values filtered before the minus process commences.
So if the value is greater than in the other column, then the lowest value should be minused from the high value, and vise versa.
also this needs to happen in a loop which iterates through the array while performing the filtering and math.

This is my code example:

```
#minus price
print('minus price trying appending')
minus_p_orgp1 = np.append(dif_p_times1, fp, axis=0)
print(minus_p_orgp1)

for ii, vv in enumerate(minus_p_orgp1):
    print('greater')
    greater_1 = np.all(ii > 0, axis=0)
    greater_0 = np.all(ii <= 0, axis=0)
    if greater_1 < greater_0:
        iit = greater_0 - greater_1
    if greater_1 > greater_0:
        iit = greater_1 - greater_0
        print(iit, ii, vv)

ssss = np.zeros(minus_p_orgp1.size - 1)
for i in range(len(minus_p_orgp1) - 1):
    if minus_p_orgp1[i] < minus_p_orgp1[i]:
        ssss[i] = minus_p_orgp1[i + 1] - minus_p_orgp1[i]
    elif minus_p_orgp1[i + 1] > minus_p_orgp1[i]:
        ssss[i] = minus_p_orgp1[i] - minus_p_orgp1[i + 1]
print(ssss)
```

This is a print of the array where the upper vector is def_p_time1, and lower vector is fp:

```
  minus price trying appending
[[79340.33057205 78379.24102508 72188.80527274 76557.26239563
  72857.90423589 71137.7943199 ]
 [43528.22       43705.         43931.07       44571.24
  44330.43       44465.64      ]]
```

Any suggestions as to what i can do to achieve my goal?

I have also tried to do the process with just having the array being two seperate vectors with size 6, 1.
But that also seems very difficult, let me know what you think.

i have also just tried this:
however it just prints out zeros when running the code:

```
trii = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
print(trii)
print(minus_p_orgp1[~(trii >= 1)])
print('it works')
itt = minus_p_orgp1[~(trii >= 1)]
itt1 = minus_p_orgp1[~(trii >= 0)]
sssss = np.zeros(dif_p_times1.size - 1)
ssss = np.zeros(minus_p_orgp1.size - 1)
for i in range(len(dif_p_times1) - 1):
    for ii in range(len(fp) - 1):
        if itt < itt1:
            sssss[i] = itt[i] + itt1[i + 1]
            ssss[i, ii] = fp[ii + 1] - dif_p_times1[i]

        elif itt > itt1:
            sssss[i] = itt[i + 1] + itt1[i]
            ssss[i, ii] = dif_p_times1[i] - fp[ii + 1]
print(sssss)

[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1]]
[63455.70703442 68744.47486851 77804.44752373 79686.34612013
 69322.78250338 83255.08459329]
it does something
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

new attempt however it still doesnt work:

```
ssss = np.zeros(minus_p_orgp1.size - 1)
x = minus_p_orgp1[::2]
y = minus_p_orgp1[::-2]
z = ssss[::2]

for z, x, y in range(len(minus_p_orgp1) - 1):
    
    if x[i + 1] < y[i]:
        z[i] = y[i + 1] - x[i]
    elif x[i + 1] > y[i]:
        z[i] = x[i + 1] - y[i]
print(z)
```

Best regards.

Mathias.

Comment: The rest of your variable declarations(i.e. `np`), and a sample of the data will help in getting you answers.

Comment: `np.abs(A-B)` for 2 1d arrays.

Comment: Hey tinstaafl i tried to give some extra information on it to show what data im working with. 

and hpaulj, i dont think abs will work, could you put some context to how i should implement it?